# emmip() - what does the y-axis represent when an offset was included

Tags: data-visualization, interaction, lsmeans, marginal-effect, interactive-visualization

I used emmip() to create a graph showing an interaction-style plot. In the model (GLMM, poisson distribution) that I fed into the graph the dependent variable (number of visits, count) was adjusted by using an offset (days).

```
y <- emmip(model1, Group ~ Phase,CIs=TRUE) + My_Theme + labs(x = "Phase", y = "ln(visits)")
```

I am now wondering if the y-axis of the produced graph shows a count or a rate? If it is count, I probably need to describe the figure with "Estimated number of visits..." in the title. However, in the text of the results, when I explain the model, I talk about incursion rate to acknowledge the input of the offset? Is that correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to show your parameter settings for `emmip()`, as that determines the type of prediction returned. Note that software-specific questions are off-topic here, although interpretation of different types of predictions (e.g., "link" vs "response") and how offsets are taken into account probably is on-topic. You might consider replacing one of your tags with `lsmeans`, to attract the attention of those fluent in use of the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans).

Comment: Hi @EdM, thank you, I considered your advice and edited my post.

Comment: Thanks. It would help if you could also show the formula for `model1` in the question. Details on how the offset was incorporated into the model, the number of levels of `Group` and `Phase`, and what interactions were included might be important.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the offset is *included* in the predictions. If you want a rate, add `offset = 0` to the call.

Comment: Oh, and if you want estimated count, add `type = "response"` instead. In other words, what is shown with neither of these is on the log(count) scale.

Comment: thank you for your response. So, if the offset is included in the predictions as in my example, it means that I get the results on the log(count) scale, correct?

Comment: Yes, unless you do type = "response", in which case the estimated log counts are back-transformed

Comment: Thanks a million!